# Tiling circles intersection with squares

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Is there an algorithm to calculate the amount of $1\times 1$ tiles that the intersection of $2$ circles lies into, given 2 circles in a $30\times 30$ grid with their radiuses and centers?

What I tried was approximating by using the line between the intersection points but this doesn't work when the intersection is wider than $1$ line of tiles.

Another version of this question is how can I check if a tile with given coordinates lies in the intersection of $2$ circles.

Comment: Do the 1x1 tiles have to be contained completely in the intersection or do they just have to touch the intersection?

Comment: @Neo a part of the tile has to lie in the intersection. So not completely.